# Insertar caracteres con tildes en sqlite usando la interfaz

Tags: c++, sqlite

Cómo puedo insertar caracteres con tildes mediante el siguiente código en una base de datos de sqlite.Por ejemplo los nombres Ramón y Alñen. Al intentar insertar caracteres con tildes o ñ, estos son sustituidos por el caracter ? en la base de datos de sqlite.
Esto me crea un problema cuando intento hacer búsquedas.
En el siguiente código, que escogí de un libro de sqlite, primero creo la base de datos y luego intento llenar una tabla con algunos ejemplos y entonces me surge el problema. he intentado utilizando libretias como SQLiteC++ pero obtengo el mismo resultado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
      printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
   }
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   sqlite3 *db;
   char *zErrMsg = 0;
   int rc;
   char *sql;
   /* Open database */
   rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
   if( rc ){
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      return(0);
   }else{
      fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
   }


   /* Create SQL statement */
   sql = "CREATE TABLE COMPANY(" \
   "ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," \
   "NAME TEXT NOT NULL," \
   "AGE INT NOT NULL," \
   "ADDRESS CHAR(50)," \
   "SALARY REAL );";
   /* Execute SQL statement */
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
   if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   }else{
      fprintf(stdout, "Table created successfully\n");
   }


   /* Create SQL statement */
   sql = "INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) " \
   "VALUES (1, 'Ramón', 32, 'California', 20000.00 ); " \
   "INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) " \
   "VALUES (2, 'Alñen', 25, 'Texas', 15000.00 ); " \
   "INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)" \
   "VALUES (3, 'Teddy', 23, 'Norway', 20000.00 );" \
   "INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)" \
   "VALUES (4, 'Mark', 25, 'Rich-Mond ', 65000.00 );";
   /* Execute SQL statement */
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
   if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   }else{
      fprintf(stdout, "Records created successfully\n");
   }
   sqlite3_close(db);
   return 0;
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: ¿ Como sabes que se insertan mal ?

Comment: Porque cuando reviso la base de datos en vez de aparecer Ramón aparece Ram?n